# How to Toggle a UIMenu Action

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a UIMenu with one of the options to be show / Hide. I want the title to be show when I am hiding some contents in the view and the title to be hide when I am showing some contents in the view. I added a global boolean to the viewcontroller class. Is there a way to toggle the title of the menu option based on the value of the global boolean?

```
 let menu = UIMenu(title: "menu", children: [
            UIAction(title: "show", handler: menuHandler)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable in place of title string:

```
var theTitle: String = ""
    
if myBoolVar == true {
    theTitle = "show"
} else {
    theTitle = "hide"
}
    
let menu = UIMenu(title: "menu", children: [
    UIAction(title: theTitle, handler: menuHandler)])
```

Using a **ternary** expression, that can be shortened to:

```
let theTitle: String = myBoolVar ? "show" : "hide"

let menu = UIMenu(title: "menu", children: [
    UIAction(title: theTitle, handler: menuHandler)])
```

or even like this (although, it sacrifices some readability):

```
let menu = UIMenu(title: "menu", children: [
    UIAction(title: myBoolVar ? "show" : "hide", handler: menuHandler)])
```